# kafka streams - all group members handle a global event

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My question is: how should I structure my kafka application to react from a "global" event that happens in a single partition of a topic using another topic that has multiple partitions?

If I've got the following scenario:
I've got a `gigs` topic, which gets a new message every time a new gig is announced a country, key is the name of the artist, value is an avro object with date, location etc. The topic has 1
partition.

Example key: `Abba`
Example value: `{"date": "2020-08-21T09:00:00Z", "venue":"The O2 London"}`

I've got another compacted topic called `subscribes`, which contains users that subscribed to artist and they want to receive a notification when a gig is announced for an artist they're interested in. The key here is an avro key with userId and artist name as value, the value is an avro object with email and other preferences. The topic has 10 partitions.

Example key: `{"user": 123, "artist": "Abba"}`
Example value: `{"email": "123@email.com", ...}`

I have many users, but not so many gigs, I want to run 10 instances of the app, as that's the partition count of the `subscribes` topic.

The application consumes both topics, when a gig is produce to `gigs` every user that has a message in the `subscribes` topic where key.artist equals the key from `gigs` produce a message to a third topic. I could achieve this with a scan over a local store built from `subscribes`.

How would someone go and use kafka streams (or just simply consumers) for an application like this? The documentation mentions global tables as a way to broadcast an event to all members, but with that I've run into different issues:

1. If I write this app with a KTable from `subscribes` and a GlobalTable from `gigs` then I can't join the two using the dsl. A user can be in `subscribes` for an unknown length of time, so I can't use a KStream to join with the GlobalTable.
2. Using the processor api I can't forward from the global context (global table from `gigs`) to the local context (where I could access a local queryable store from `subscribes`) when a new message is consumed.
3. Even if I could forward from global context to a local one in 2. I'd have the problem that whenever the app restarts it'd read the topic from the beginning as globaltables don't keep offsets, so I'd end up sending the same messages again and again to the output topic.

Solution I thought of:
Consume `gigs` topics and and produce to `gigs_broadcast` that has 10 partitions and writes the same message to every partition. This way every member could have the same partitions assigned from each store, so whenever a message is arrives in `gigs` now it'd be in the local context and could forward it to another processor that has access to a queryable store from `subscribes` to do a scan.

Is there a better solution? Perhaps by using consumers + producers instead of kafka streams? Ideally I know I'd have the same keys for both topics, but I am not sure if that's feasible: I'd have to rekey the `subscribes` stream to the artist, do groupBy, aggregate a list of userIds per artist then join that to the `gigs` topic to flatMap over them to produce a `gigs_customers` where the key is the same as `subscribes` and the value is the same.

Comment: I think what you've described is probably the best way to do it:

Consumes from subscribes and immediately puts each subscriber into a queryable state store.
Consumes from gigs and looks up subscribers in the store and forwards to the third topic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a foreign-key join to me. You can read both topics as KTables, and use the artist as join attribute. Your user/subscription table would be your left hand side table, and you use the key-extractor to extract to artist as join attribute and join to the gigs table.